# How to trace the program

Tags: java, trace

I am asked to trace this program just before the if statement in the isPrime method  is executed (just at the first iteration of the for loop). So How to trace this program? what is in the memory? what is the output?

```
package hwprime;
public class HWPrime {

    public static boolean isPrime (int number) {
        for (int div =2; div <= number / 2; div++)
            if (number % div == 0)
                return false;   // we found a number div that num is divisible by
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
         System.out.println(" is a number a prime number?");
        int  x = 41;
         if (isPrime (x) )     
             System.out.println(x + " is a prime number");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Are you using an IDE?

Comment: You should look at the debuger of your IDE

Answer (score 0):

You can also use debugging tool with eclipse, just toggle a break point on the line, which you want to trace/debug.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can work with IDE such as Intellij IDEA, make a breakpoint on the for loop

```
for (int div =2; div <= number / 2; div++) //breakpoint on this line
```

then use Debug Mode. In the Watch Window, you can see the value of variables.